# Для множества точек на плоскости найти кратчайший путь, который проходит через каждую точку

Tags: алгоритм

Множество точек задается следующей картинкой:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это нарисовано в фотошопе кистью опреденного радиуса без сглаживания. Черный пиксель - точка есть, белый - точки нет.

Метрика: d = |x<sub>1</sub> - x<sub>2</sub>| + |y<sub>1</sub> - y<sub>2</sub>| (гомеоморфна евклидовой?)

Интуитивно чувствую, что способ задания множества и его вид (пиксели) можно как-то сформулировать математически и использовать для оптимизации алгоритма, но не могу понять, как именно.

Comment: Почему так много точек?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте такую математическую модель как Граф, граф очень хорошо подходит для решения данной задачи. Например почитайте это : [хабр](https://habrahabr.ru/post/65367/)

Comment: не думаю что ссылка поможет.

Comment: @pavel не имеет смысла решать за человека задачу, можно показать способ - помочь материалом. а не сразу решать за него

Comment: именно что ссылка ничем и не поможет). и это не совсем красиво, давать ссылку на букварь когда спрашивают более сложный вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

ерунда какая-то нарисована.

самый простой вариант - рекурсия с асимптотикой n!, но это тяжеловатый вариант, 
поэтому были придуманы и получили известность спец. алгоритмы, такие как [DISKRA's](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/greedy-algorithms-set-6-dijkstras-shortest-path-algorithm/), [PRIM's](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/greedy-algorithms-set-5-prims-mst-for-adjacency-list-representation/)

Comment: ну n! - перебор, но n^2 * 2 ^ n - скорее всего оптимальный. Гамильтоновы циклы быстрее не ищутся.